# Set Range to be specific lines within a cell, Microsoft VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working with a word template document that extensively uses tables to separate values. This has been great for most of my VBA code, as it makes it very simple to set values where I need to make edits. However, there is one place, in the header, where a single cell contains three lines of text. I need to set the value of JUST the first two lines in this cell.

QUESTION:
How do you set the value of JUST the first two lines of text in a given cell? Or, more broadly, can you set Range to be one line within a cell?

What I have right now, which sets Range as the whole cell and sets the value as "NEW TEXT":

```
ActiveDocument.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True

With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
 .Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "NEW TEXT"
End With
```

Thank you for any expertise you can lend me.

Comment: Capture the value of the whole cell, find the line break characters, and replace everything before the second line break?

Answer (score 1):

To replace (eg) the second line:

```
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
    .Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Paragraphs(2).Range.Text = "NEW TEXT" & vbLf
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solves it. I now see that I was being too specific in my search for the solution... could have figured out how the general line selection applied in my specific case.